# Ordering of submanifolds in a $d$-sphere $S^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

Let us be open-minded first, in order to read the question below.

> I would like to have some mathematical tools/formulations/theories to understand the ordering of submanifolds in a $d$-sphere $S^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Take the following figure for examples,
[image]

Let us limit to the $S^d = S^3$ first.

(1) Imagine the origin $X$ is a 0-dimensional point, while the submanifold with a radius $a$ is a $S^2$, called $S^2{}_a$, linking with/bounding the point $X$. There is another submanifold with a radius $b$ is a $S^2$, called $S^2{}_b$, linking with/bounding the point $X$. Here $b>a>0$, so submanifolds $X$, $S^2{}_a$, and $S^2{}_b$ all are in the $S^3$ . We see that there is an ordering of submanifolds, that

- $S^2{}_b$ bounds $S^2{}_a$, while
- $S^2{}_a$ bounds $X$,

we cannot re-order $S^2{}_a$ and $S^2{}_b$, without making these two submanifolds touching each other.

> Namely we cannot exchange the positions of $S^2{}_a$ and $S^2{}_b$ surfaces, without letting them touch each other by a smooth deformation.
>   (Let us call this case as there is an ordering of submanifolds.)

(2) Now, imagine the origin of the above figure becomes an $L$, as a 1-dimensional closed line (or a circle), while the submanifold with a radius $a$ is a $S^1$, called $S^1{}_a$, linking with the line $Y$. There is another submanifold with a radius $b$ is a $S^1$, called $S^1{}_b$, linking with the line $Y$. Here $b>a>0$, so submanifolds $Y$, $S^1{}_a$, and $S^1{}_b$ all are in the $S^3$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$). We see that there is a no natural ordering of submanifolds, that

- $S^1{}_b$ links with $Y$, while
- $S^2{}_a$ links with $Y$.

But we CAN re-order $S^1{}_a$ and $S^1{}_b$, without making these two submanifolds touching each other.

> Namely we CAN exchange the positions of $S^1{}_a$ and $S^1{}_b$ submanifold in $S^3$, without letting them touch each other by a smooth deformation.
>   (Let us call this case as there is an NO ordering of submanifolds.)

---

> - question: what is the proper mathematical tools to address the above *ordering* issues of submanifolds inside $\mathbb{S}^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d$ or any $M^d$ with all homotopy group $\pi_i(M^d)=0$ trivial? I suppose we need to understand the deformations of submanifolds, and the homology/cohomology of the spaces. (But what precisely math formulas can we check whether there is a natural ordering for these submanifolds?)

Note add: When the submanifolds $\Sigma^{d-1}_i$ are $d-1$ dimensional, where $i=1,\dots,N$ are $N$ of them, all linking with a 0-dim point (the origin $X$ in the above). There is a natural ordering of this submanifolds. (The total space is $d$-dimensional $M^d$ with all homotopy group trivial $\pi_i(M^d)=0$.) But I wonder whether there can be more natural ordering of submanifolds even for lower dimensional submanifolds $\Sigma^{j}$ for $j< d-1$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason not to just say that you have a partial order and leave it at that?  It would be pretty unrealistic to expect a full order without overdoing it and applying the well ordering principle.

Comment: thanks Carl, My understanding is that when the submanifolds $\Sigma^{d-1}_i$ are $d-1$ dimensional, where $i=1,\dots,N$ all linking with a 0-dim point. There is a natural ordering. (The total space is $d$-dimensional.) But I wonder whether there can be more natural ordering of submanifolds even for lower dimensional submanifolds.

Comment: I see, I suppose you are requiring the submanifolds to be disjoint.  But I think there is no reasonable application to other dimensions, since the reason it works for $d-1$ is that the submanifolds are separating.  You'll have problems like you mentioned, as well as problems in higher dimensions, where for example when $d=4$ youd have to order knotted spheres.

Comment: for example, if I have multi-linking such as Borromean rings in 3d, or Massey product, or higher dim analogy, maybe it is possible to replace a set of submanifolds linked with one of the ring, in a particular ("non-commutative") ordering. I was wondering. (I think that Borromean rings do not work. But maybe something would work.)